# Connecting Direction Service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've set up a map using AngularJS. The marker data is from a json file and is in working order. But I'd like the user to be able to click on a button (either from the item list or in the info window) to get directions from their current location to their selected destination.

I do not know how to connect Google Maps Direction Service to what I have. The current function is connected to the button in the marker list, not the info window. But I would like the direction service to work in either.

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the site (all source code is available) http://portlandstreetcarbars.com/streetcar-bars-map/app/#/

Here is the HTML:

```
    <h3>Click on a bar below to view its location or get directions.</h3>
        <div class="horizontal">
          <div class="table"> 
              <article class="list-group-item" id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
               <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">  
                   <div class="img-wrap"> 
                  <img id="bar-image" class="bar-image" src={{marker.image}} />
               <!-- End Image Gallery -->
                </div>   
              <h3 class="box-title">{{marker.title}}</h3>    
              </a>
              <input type='button' ng-click='getDirections(marker)' value='Get directions'>
            </article> 
        </div>
    </div>

  <h3 class="map">Click on a marker below to view its location or get directions.</h3>
   <section class="map-container">
         <div id="map"></div> 
              <h3>Directions Go here</h3> 
      <div id="panel">
         <input type='button' id="reset-map" ng-click='clearMarkers()' value='Reset Map'>
       </div>
  </section>
```

Here is the script:

```
var mapApp = angular.module('mapControllers', []);

 mapApp.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('scripts/bars.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.bars = data;

      var myLatlng100 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.522535,-122.659492);
      var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng100,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            }
      };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (bar){

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(bar.lat, bar.lng),
            title: bar.name
            });

        marker.content = '<div class="contentString"><img src="' + 
        bar.image +
        '"><br/>'+ 
        bar.address +
        ' '+ 
        bar.city +
        ', '+
        bar.state + 
        '<button ng-click="getDirections('+bar.lat+', '+bar.lng+')">Get Directions</button>' +
        '</div>';
        marker.image = bar.image;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<a href="' + bar.url + '">' +'<h2 class="info-window">' + bar.name + '</h2>' + '</a>' +  marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

      }
    var i;  
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.bars.length; i++){
        createMarker($scope.bars[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    };
    $scope.getDirections= function(marker) {
          $scope.marker = marker;
          $scope.lat = $scope.marker.position.D;
          $scope.lng = $scope.marker.position.k;
          console.log($scope.lat);

          if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation          
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {  //This gets the
              var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                       //users current
              var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                    //location
              var start = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);     //Creates variable for map coordinates
              var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
              var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map);
              directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
              var request = {
                  origin: start,
                  destination: new google.maps.LatLng( $scope.lat, $scope.lng),
                  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
                };
             directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
          //Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
          } 
        };
        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
              if (errorFlag) {
                var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
              } else {
                content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
              }

              var options = {
                map: $scope.map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
                content: content
              };

              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
              map.setCenter(options.position);

    }
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Did not compute");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I had my getDir function incorrectly inside the controller (apparently).

I removed it, added map as a parameter and it works. But the direction path doesn't render on the map. So if anyone has any ideas as to how to fix this...